# инициализация int[] по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Наткнулся на интересную особенность при инициализации массива int.

```
int arr1[10];
int main() {
    int arr2[10];
    return 0;
}
```

Все значения `arr1` равны 0, а все значения `arr2` значениями -858993460 ( мое предположение, что это просто неинициализированная память)

Вопрос такой: почему снаружи `main` компилятор делает что-то типа этого `int arr1[10] = {};` , а внутри не делает ничего?

Comment: Потому что снаружи - глобальная переменная, а внутри локальная. Дальше читайте разницу между их инициализацией..

Comment: все глобалные и статические переменные инициализируются  значениями по умолчанию. Компилятор делает это автоматически, а в функциях(локальные) нужно инициализировать  самим

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Таковы правила инициализации всех объектов со *статическим классом хранения*. И в С, и в С++ они подвергаются нулевой инициализации, если вы не предоставили явного инициализатора.

В С++ процесс инициализации существенно более сложен, чем в С, т.к. С++ поддерживает динамическую инициализацию, но к вашему случаю это не относится.

Автоматические переменные тривиальных типов не подвергаются никакой инициализации, если вы явно не укажете инициализатор.